# Python argparse.ArgumentParser - option name starting with number?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to add an option starting with number, e.g., `--3d` here:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--3d", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args(['--3d'])
print(args)
```

`parser` works well, but `args` looks like this and I don't know how to get the value:

```
Namespace(**{'3d': True})
```

I've tried `args.3d`, `args("3d")`, `args["3d"]`, `args{"3d"}`, etc, and none of them works.

I know I can add `dest` in `add_argument()` to work around this problem, but I still want to learn how to get the data in `**{}`.

Comment: `getattr(args, '3d')`?

Comment: Thanks! So **{} represents the attributes that cannot use dot notation?

Comment: Ah, I found the **{} is just the customized repr string of the args object.  It is not a syntax.

Comment: `foo(**{'3d': True})` is equivalent to `foo(3d=True)`, just unpacking a dict into named arguments. The difference is that `3d=…` is an illegal literal, and illegal for the same reason to use as plain `args.3d`. However, using a string for it and alternative methods to unpack/access it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of

```
Namespace(**{'3d': True})
```

as a way of displaying a value whose name is not a valid attribute.

'3d' can be used as a `dict` key, as in `vars(args)['3d']`.

`getattr` is the general purpose accessor that `argparse` uses internally.

Another option is use `dest` to set a different name.

The things you tried were wrong because:

```
args.3d  # bad attribute name
args("3d")  # args is not a function
args["3d"]  # args is not a dict
args{"3d"}  # bad syntax
```

---

That ** syntax does work with creating a `argparse.Namespace` object, but it's not something that we normally use:

```
In [152]: argparse.Namespace(foo='bar')
Out[152]: Namespace(foo='bar')
In [153]: argparse.Namespace(foo='bar', **{'3d':'x'})
Out[153]: Namespace(foo='bar', **{'3d': 'x'})
In [154]: getattr(_, '3d')
Out[154]: 'x'
In [155]: vars(__)
Out[155]: {'foo': 'bar', '3d': 'x'}
In [156]: _['3d']
Out[156]: 'x'
```

Basically `argparse` returns values in a simple `Namespace` classed object, one that gives easy attribute access for valid names, but also lets you, the user, use messy names.  But the details come down to what's valid Python.